# MySql Update and Select in same query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-update

In MySql, I try to do an UPDATE and a SELECT in the same query.
I have try many examples from this site, but nothing work. (Variables, sub-query...)

```
UPDATE receipt
SET status = IF(status=1, 0, 1)
WHERE idreceipt = 220

SELECT status
FROM receipt
WHERE idreceipt = 220
```

Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to do?  `update` and `select` are different commands in SQL.  Your queries are fine, as written.

Comment: "in the same query"? You can't just slap two different queries together and expect it to work. especially since you don't have a `;` in there to terminate your `update`...

Comment: Thank Marc, I figured out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the above commands are fine for you as they are, just enter the semicolons at the end of the statements:

```
UPDATE receipt
SET status = IF(status=1, 0, 1)
WHERE idreceipt = 220;

SELECT status
FROM receipt
WHERE idreceipt = 220;
```